# Rewriting rules in Apache for a different port

Tags: spring, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My Apache(Tomcat)-Spring server runs on port 8080. I want to make a call to localhost default port(80) and want a redirection to take place to port 8080.

I enabled mod-rewrite and the following rule from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite) works fine.

```
RewriteRule ^orange.html$ apple.html
```

I read the rewrite rules of apache from [Apache URL Rewriting Doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

However the following rules does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://localhost:8080/$1 [L,R]
```

My intention is to allow cross domain support without enabling CORS in spring controller.(This is a hard rule)

The .htaccess is located in /var/www/html.
Also I do not want other requests to be redirected on the port 8080 except which are on localhost/(my_specified_string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ProxyPass is what was needed here and not rewrite engine.

Following config lines in the `000-default.conf` present in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` did the trick.

```
ProxyPass /servlet-name http://localhost:8080/servlet-name
ProxyPassReverse /servlet-name http://localhost:8080/servlet-name
```

This redicrected any request on `/servlet-name` to `http://localhost:8080/servlet-name`.

One can replace "servlet-name" above with their respective servlet name.

More info here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^my_specified_string http://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

"redirect" is not the correct term in this scenario.
The ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives setup a reverse proxy, so you are not redirecting the browser to a new URL, you are accepting traffic on one port and reverse proxying that traffic through apache httpd (mod_proxy) to the destination server:port